# URL redirection from Apache to Tomcat using mod_jk

Tags: mod-jk

My apache document root is `/srv/www/htdocs/` and my url is https://internal.net/

My requirement is to open a URL https://internal.net/jenkins-project/ which should have document root as `/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/jenkins-project/` rather than looking into `/srv/www/htdocs/jenkins-project/`

I tried using mod_jk and have configured a worker property with name worker1 and am using it in `httpd.conf` as mentioned below

`JkMount /jenkins-project/*` worker1

But still throwing an error

File does not exist: `/srv/www/htdocs/jenkins-project/`

Comment: I already tried ProxyPass method as mentioned below

ProxyPass / http://domain.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://domain.com:8080/

This is working fine, but my requirement is to use mod_jk method which is mentioned above

Comment: copy paste your log + workers.properties + mod_jk.conf file

Answer (score 0):

I have used below code in tomcat's server.xml and restarted Tomcat. Its working fine now.

```
    <Context path="/jenkins-project" docBase="jenkins-project" debug="0" reloadable="true">
            <Logger className="org.apache.catalina.logger.FileLogger" prefix="jenkins-project" suffix=".log" timestamp="false"/>
    </Context>
```